# how to create a layout like “1-day” view of google calendar application

Tags: android

[image]

I don't know how add the events to the timeline. I've done my timeline with a ListView. The events can be of 1h, 1,5h, 2h, 2.5h, .... and I don't know which kind of view, and how add to the timeline.

Any idea or example?

Comment: will you attach screenshots for it?

Comment: Please check screenshots

Answer (score 2):

Use this library maybe your problem is resolving.
https://github.com/jlurena/revolvingweekview